# Eclipse - I'm looking for View. Show me files modified today

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for some View in eclipse, which show me modified files by me today. 
I have many projects, and naturally i can use SVN but I would like somethin easy. 
Any view can do this requirments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Finally i found soultions, but not in Eclipse.

Tortoise SVN has option:  Right click on my workspace and choose: "Check for Modifications".
Date sort and I have what i want.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there is no specific view that does that, but, you can use an external tool for that matter. If you are on a Unix box (Linux/OS X), the following command will look for files under the current directory which were modified in the last 24 hours:

```
find . -mtime -1 -print
```

On Windows, you might want to use cygwin or find an alternative command.

To define the command:

1. Go to Run menu → External Tools → External Tools Configuration
2. Create a new program execution configuration.
3. In location enter the find command path (`/usr/bin/find`) and in arguments enter: `${selected_resource_loc} -mtime -1 -print`
4. Save your configuration.

In the arguments, you are telling Eclipse to enter the selected resource location as the search directory. Now, you can select a folder or file, and run the configuration from the External Tools button in the toolbar (green arrow with red toolbox icon).

Comment: Depending on your purpose this might require some creative filtering, since it includes all files modified, no matter by who or why, (.svn, .class, .jar, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Right Click on Project-> Restore from Local History..  this is closer answer to your question, I can not think anything that answers your question.

Comment: is this for Git only? I don't have such option in Eclipse Mars with CVS.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no utility that shows you the files modified "today" but there is a utility that shows you the files modified locally i.e. the dirty files.

Go to 
<kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Open Perspective</kbd>  -> <kbd>Other..</kbd>  -> <kbd>Team Synchronizing</kbd> and then click on the populate button

It will show you all the outgoing changes without going to the svn server.

In case you want to see the incoming and conflicting changes also, you will have to click the synchronize button that will check with the server to see for changes/conflicts etc.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/). It it already integrated in your eclipse. just start a new task before starting the changes any it will "record" all changes made and display them in the package explorer view.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today, only I wanted to know which files was edited last friday.
I realized there was a quite simple and flexible solution to solve this problem.

(I use windows)
-To the folder of the project. Search for all files.
-Sort them by edit date

There is one drawback to this solution though! It will also show you folder!
To solve this problem I searched with *.JS which meant I saw JS and JSP files.

In many cases this simple solution will be sufient.